Proof check: prove that if f is derivable in $x_0$ then $\ \lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) = f(x_0)$
We have: $f$ is derivable in $x_0$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\lim_{x\to{x_0}} {\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}}$ exists and is finite.
Then by the definition of a finite limit we have:
$$
\exists l \in \mathbb{R} \forall \varepsilon > 0 \, \, \exists \, \alpha >0 \, \, \forall x \in D_f:
0 < |x-x_0|< \alpha \Rightarrow \Bigg|\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}-l\Bigg|< \varepsilon 
$$
Thus:
$$\Bigg|\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}- l \Bigg| < \varepsilon$$
$$\Rightarrow -\varepsilon +l<\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} < \varepsilon + l
$$
$$\Rightarrow (-\varepsilon +l)(x-x_0)<{f(x)-f(x_0)} < (\varepsilon +l)(x-x_0)$$
Notice that when $x$ aproches $x_0$, we get $f(x)=f(x_0)$.
Let $g$ be the function defined as follows: $g(x)=\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$.
Therefore:
$$
\exists l \in \mathbb{R} \forall \varepsilon > 0 \, \, \exists \, \alpha > 0 \, \, \forall x \in D_f: 0<|x-x_0| < \alpha \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\varepsilon 
$$
Notice that $]x_0-r;x_0+r[-x_0\subset D_g $. Then:
$$\ \lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) = f(x_0)$$
Please share your thoughts about my proof, I am open to other proofs but it would be preferable to just use the definitions and theorems related to both derivates and limits (in my case). Thank you all!

Edit: I added the missing quantifier($\exists l\in \mathbb R$), and the missing -$\epsilon$ and also the $\alpha$ in $0<|x-x_0|<\alpha$ instead of $0$

Your proof seems weird, in that you have $0 < |x - x_0| < 0$, how could $0 < 0$? And later, $\epsilon + l < \epsilon + l$?

It was a typo it is suppose to be $0<|x-x_0|<\alpha$ and it is $-\epsilon + l< on left hand side

My latex skills are a little bad that's why it takes so long to edit and tha's why I also do a lot of typos

$x-x_0$ Is it necessarily positive?

No it's not necessary

Sure and also thank you for your advice I really apreciate that

"Q&A for people studying math at any level" :)

If $f$ is derivable in $x_0$ then it exists $\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} = L \in \mathbb{R}$. So $$\lim_{x \to x_0} (x-x_0) \cdot \lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=0$$ which implies $\lim_{x \to x_0} (f(x)-f(x_0)) = 0$, so $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = f(x_0)$.

What did you do to get the second step ? Operations on finite limits right ?

Yes. Limit of product is product of limits

I see two points :

"$-\varepsilon +l<\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} < \varepsilon + l$ $$\Rightarrow (-\varepsilon +l)(x-x_0)<{f(x)-f(x_0)} < (\varepsilon +l)(x-x_0)$$"

can't be written unless $x-x_0>0$
Hint : $\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}-l=\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)-l(x-x_0)}{x-x_0}$ and carefully consider the cases where $x-x_0<0$

Once you've proven that $|f(x)-f(x_0)-l(x-x_0)|\le \epsilon|x-x_0|$, you have $$-\epsilon|x-x_0|+l|x-x_0|\le f(x)-f(x_0)\le \epsilon|x-x_0|+l|x-x_0|$$ and it is easy to conclude.

Considering your function $g$ is not useful. And what you write is not clear.
Note that $x_0\notin D_g$.

Note also that if we introduce the function noted $D_f(x_0):u\to l\times u$, and if you know the notation $o$, we have also proven that $$f(x)-f(x_0)-D_f(x_0)(x-x_0)=o(x-x_0)$$

ah yes I forgot to write ]x_0-r;x_0+r[-{x_0}

we have Big o And little o in a upcoming chapter so it is a useful and interesting aproach thank you again !

Since:
$$f'(x_0) := \lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}h = \lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x - x_0}$$
The numerator $f(x)-f(x_0)$ must approach $0$ for the limit to converge. That means $f(x)\to f(x_0)$.

I apreciate your comment, but in my opinion it's not very rigourous. Also we can't really do that since we get an indeterminent form 0/0

It is quite rigorous. If the limit diverges, the function is not differentiable, of course. I don't understand your last remark.

@RaidZougari seems rigorous enough to me.

I don't know.  The proof is just convincing to me. It doesn't show something. That's just my opinion. It is closer to litterature than it is to formal math proofs. I hope you get what I mean. It is a good way to convince yourself after proving, but it isn't to me enough to really be sure it is true. A formal proof is always better.
